# Prove $\int_0^1 (\sqrt[n]{1-x^n}-x)^2 dx=\frac{1}{3}$ for $n \gt 0$

Tags: integration

I have found that the value of the integral below is always $1/3$ for all positive $n$.
$$\int_0^1 (\sqrt[n]{1-x^n}-x)^2 dx$$
Can anyone prove this for me? Thank you.

Comment: Idea: if the integral is $I(n)$, take a derivative wrt $n$ and show that $I'(n) = 0$ (which it is). Then you can just evaluate for one easy value of $n$, say $n=1$.

Comment: What is the source of the question? What have you tried ? This is a very low quality way of asking questions heree

Comment: @jimjim I am sorry, I haven't used this cite very much yet. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explore the symmetry to  integrate the general case

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 (\sqrt[n]{1-x^n}-x)^{2k} \overset{1-x^n \to x^n}{dx}\\
= &\int_0^1 (x-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})^{2k} d(-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})\\
 =&\ \frac12 \int_0^1 (x-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})^{2k} d(x-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})
=\frac1{2k+1}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain the second equality? And if there is $1/2$ in front of the integral, isn't the answer $1\over{2(2k+1)}$?

Comment: @Zjjorsia Second equality 
\begin{align}
I 
=&\frac12 \int_0^1 (x-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})^{2k} dx+\frac12\int_0^1 (x-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})^{2k} d(-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})\\
 =&\ \frac12 \int_0^1 (x-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})^{2k} d(x-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})
\end{align} Also $$(x-\sqrt[n]{1-x^n})^{2k+1}|_0^1 =1-(-1)=2$$ which cancels $\frac12$

Comment: Wow I didn't know I can do $\int y da+\int y db=\int y d(a+b)$. I've never seen it before, can you please me tell the name of the theorem or somewhere to look for?

Comment: @Zjjorsia it is the derivative addition rule i.e. $(f(x)+g(x))’=f’(x)+g’(x)$

Answer (score 6):

put $x^n=y$ then $dx=\frac{1}{n} y^{\frac{1}{n}-1} dy$ So
$$ I=\int_0^1 \left((1-x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}-x\right)^2dx=\int_0^1 \left((1-y)^{\frac{1}{n}}-y^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^2\frac{1}{n} y^{\frac{1}{n}-1} dy $$
So
$$ I=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 \left((1-y)^{\frac{2}{n}}y^{\frac{1}{n}-1} -2(1-y)^{\frac{1}{n}}y^{\frac{2}{n}-1}+y^{\frac{3}{n}-1} \right) dy$$
then
$$ I=\frac{1}{n} \left(\beta\left(\frac{2}{n}+1,\frac{1}{n}\right)-2\beta\left(\frac{1}{n}+1,\frac{2}{n}\right)+\frac{n}{3} \right) $$
now we have from beta function
$$ \beta\left(\frac{2}{n}+1,\frac{1}{n}\right)-2\beta\left(\frac{1}{n}+1,\frac{2}{n}\right)=0$$
So
$$I=\frac{1}{3}$$
also we can get this result without using beta function we have
$$ \int_0^1  (1-y)^{\frac{2}{n}}y^{\frac{1}{n}-1} dy =\int_0^1  y^{\frac{2}{n}}(1-y)^{\frac{1}{n}-1} dy $$
now using integral by part
$$\int_0^1  (1-y)^{\frac{2}{n}}y^{\frac{1}{n}-1} dy=2\int_0^1 (1-y)^{\frac{1}{n}}y^{\frac{2}{n}-1}dy$$
therefore
$$I=\frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 y^{\frac{3}{n}-1} dy=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: The result is amazing for $\int_0^1 (\sqrt[n]{1-x^n}-x)^{2k}\, dx$. By the way, (+1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!